# How to sort the list based on dictionary of dictionary

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, nested

I am trying to sort the following list of dictionary  based on the sum of value of inner dictionary (a+b+C)

```
d2=[{'id': 255, 's': {'a':  50, 'b': 60, 'c': 0}},
    {'id': 257, 's': {'a': 100, 'b': 10, 'c': 0}}, 
    {'id': 285, 's': {'a':  20, 'b': 10, 'c': 0}}]
```

Comment: how do you want to resolve ties? `{'id': 255, ..` and `{'id': 257..` have the same sum (`110`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the solution,

```
sorted(d2, key=lambda x:x['s']['a']+x['s']['b']+x['s']['c'])
```

Comment: or `key=lambda x:sum(x['s'].values())`

Comment: @Ashishsiwalkar : Do you want 257 first and then 255? Is this what you expect

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
d2 = sorted(d2, key=lambda x: sum(x['s'].values()))
```

Comment: this creates a new list that will be unassigned. It does not operate in-place on `d2`. So either do `d2 = sorted(...` or `d2.sort(..`

Answer (score 1):

To sort inplace use the `list.sort` and use required dictionary key in key.

**Ex:**

```
d2.sort(key=lambda item:sum(item['s'].values()))
```